# In OpenCV, converting 2d image point to 3d world unit vector

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I have calibrated my camera with OpenCV (findChessboard etc) so I have:
- Camera Distortion Coefficients & Intrinsics matrix
- Camera Pose information (Translation & Rotation, computed separatedly via other means) as Euler Angles & a 4x4
- 2D points within the camera frame

How can I convert these 2D points into 3D unit vectors pointing out into the world? I tried using cv::undistortPoints but that doesn't seem to do it (only returns 2D remapped points), and I'm not exactly sure what method of matrix math to use to model the camera via the Camera intrinsics I have.

Comment: What 2D points are you talking about?

Comment: 2D image (pixel) coordinates captured within the camera's frame.  Essentially, given a 2D image coordinate and the above data, I should be able to construct a 3D unit vector pointing at that 2D image coordinate from the Camera.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Convert your 2d point into a homogenous point (give it a third coordinate equal to 1) and then multiply by the inverse of your camera intrinsics matrix.  For example

```
cv::Matx31f hom_pt(point_in_image.x, point_in_image.y, 1);
hom_pt = camera_intrinsics_mat.inv()*hom_pt; //put in world coordinates

cv::Point3f origin(0,0,0);
cv::Point3f direction(hom_pt(0),hom_pt(1),hom_pt(2));

//To get a unit vector, direction just needs to be normalized
direction *= 1/cv::norm(direction);
```

origin and direction now define the ray in world space corresponding to that image point.  Note that here the origin is centered on the camera, you can use your camera pose to transform to a different origin.  Distortion coefficients map from your actual camera to the pinhole camera model and should be used at the very beginning to find your actual 2d coordinate.  The steps then are

1. Undistort 2d coordinate with distortion coefficients
2. Convert to ray (as shown above)
3. Move that ray to whatever coordinate system you like.

Comment: You forgot to normalize hom_pt. :)

Comment: @IanMedeiros do you mean to make it a unit vector or to make the 3rd element 1?  The vector defined by those points is correct with or without any kind of normalizing, after multiplying by the inverse of the camera matrix the 3rd element can be interpreted as a z coordinate.

Comment: Actually, I've upvoted your answer but now I'm not sure if its correct. I think that you need to convert the 2D coordinates from pixels to world coordinates using the intrinsic matrix before doing the homogenization that you are talking about. Than you can transform it using the camera pose information to get the ray direction.

Comment: @IanMedeiros I intended camera_mat to be the intrinsics, I updated the answer to make that more clear.  Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Now, are you sure that multiplying the homogenized 2D point by the intrinsic matrix will result in an unit vector? If not, it's necessary to normalize it.

Comment: @IanMedeiros No, it will usually not result in a unit vector, but why would you need to normalize it?  Two points define a line and the defined line does not change if direction is normalized.  I agree that normalizing it is useful in many situations but the answer is no less right without it.

Comment: @IanMedeiros you are completely right, I didn't notice that, thank you

Comment: what about camera distortion?

Comment: @EBAG Camera distortion should be represented as part of your camera intrinsics matrix